# Network adapter for windows

Tags: java, windows, networking, adapter, tunnel

I would like to create some tunnel software which should integrate into Windows by installing a network adapter. I can't find any good way to get started on this topic. Is it somehow possible to develop such an adpater in java?

These cisco solutions manage to create a tunnel by only allowing the browser to run some java app, so it must be possible.

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated.

Comment: What type of Tunnel are you looking to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the way OpenVPN works. It installs an adapter and creates a VPN Tunnel. It's Open Source and available for Windows, Linux, etc.

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html

Also look into TUN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP